# Images centering by themselves

Tags: html, css

I've run into something I've never seen before and I cannot find anything about how to fix it and I've been searching for two days.

I have a wrapper. In the wrapper, there are three divs across (new_initiatives, logo, and options) and one underneath (btns) and the wrapper ends. A sticky footer is below the wrapper and uses flex for the list items in the footer.

In the btns div, I have twelve buttons I want to display in two rows and I want the buttons to spread out to take up the available space. No problem, I've done it before. However, the buttons are acting like I've centered a div on the page. When I add a margin or padding to the right side of the button, it scoots one button down to another row.

I have not centered the div because it is 100% of the wrapper div. The only centered div is the logo. I was just going to space the buttons using margin. I even tried using a table and it did the same thing.

There might be something in the CSS but I can't find it right now. I'm posting my CSS but I'll have to scrub the HTML to post it. Let me know if I should do that. Also let me know what I missed including.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVV6u.png)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

p,
td,
li,
div {
  font: .95em/1.25em verdana, "sans serif";
}

h1 {
  font: bold small-caps 1.5em verdana, "sans serif";
  padding: .05em 0 .25em 0;
  color: #1349B3;
}

h2 {
  font: bold small-caps 1em verdana, "sans serif";
  padding: .05em 0 .25em 0;
  color: #1349B3;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body>#wrapper {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.footer {
  height: 160px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: -160px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
}

#initiatives {
  width: 23%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 2px;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 410px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #FFFB41;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
}

#option {
  width: 23%;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 30px;
  right: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 410px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #B3DEFF;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#btns {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 475px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/*#btns img {
margin-right: 50px;
}*/

.footer ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer ul li {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="toolbox.css">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">


<div id="initiatives">
<h1>New initiatives</h1>
</div>

<div id="logo">
<img class="logo" src="images/elect_eng_toolbox.png" />
</div>

<div id="option">
<h1>Options</h1>
</div>

<div id="btns">

<div style="width: 100%; margin: 5px auto;">
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; margin: 5px auto;">
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
<img src="images/btn_blank.png" />
</div>

</div>


</div>

<div class="footer">

<ul>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>

</ul>

&copy Copyright 2017 Southern Company
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: add the html to the snippet so that we can see the issue clearer

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without your markup.

Comment: Added the HTML.

Comment: `margin:5px auto` may be causing the problem try removing the auto.  Hard to be sure without real images. can you add the images/provide a link to  the site showing the issue?

Comment: Use placeholder images, e.g: https://placehold.it/300x200 (https://placeholder.com/) - for the sake of this demonstration.

Comment: Added an image to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is the `top:475` on the `#btn`  This is forcing the buttons to be in the scope of the two divs that are floating. You also need to clear above and below your buttons and `text-align: center` the `#btn`

See my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/agqnqdL7/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floats by either adding clear:both to your #btns css or creating an empty div with the style="clear:both" underneath your #option, but still above your #btns.

Clearing floats is complicated to explain, but here's a link https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: I've tried clear: both before but I tried it again. The buttons were pushed below the footer with the footer hiding the half of the first row and both rows left-aligned.

Comment: The rows are left aligned by default, if you want them centered you'll have to use text-align center on the img containing divs. Also the bttns are appearing below the footer because of a top:475px (see link). if you remove this it should fix it. I would also remove the negative margin on the footer, but have not done that in this fiddle. Also your imgs are overlapping the above floats because they each have a top:30px set. https://jsfiddle.net/k9pakypt/2/